# Is there a free alternative to Gelcompar for comparing banding patterns across multiple gels?

Tags: microbiology, gel-electrophoresis, software

In order to run my microbial community samples from my experiments through [DGGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dgge#Denaturing_gradient_gel_electrophoresis), I was required to use multiple gels.

Thus it is necessary to compare banding patterns across more than one gel.  This means that I need some way of assessing whether the 4th band on gel #1 is the same OTU as the 4th band on gel #2.

The industry standard for this procedure seems to be the [Gelcompar](http://gelcompar.com/) software.  Unfortunately this software is greater than $10,000 and is proprietary (thus, not open science friendly).

**Does there exist a free (ideally as in speech and beer) alternative to Gelcompar?**

Comment: Do you have any programming skills? Because ImageJ immediately comes to mind. You'd just have to modify a little the already existing gel tools...

Comment: I second the ImageJ recommendation. It's already well setup for gel analysis, and people do use it for DGGE (e.g http://www.springerimages.com/Images/LifeSciences/1-10.1007_s10482-007-9143-9-0)

Comment: Here's an ImageJ mailing list entry about DGGE... http://imagej.1557.n6.nabble.com/gel-analysis-td3703740.html

Comment: Phoretix 1D Pro is a cheaper alternative and yealy licenses are available

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

Pavel, A. B. & Vasile, C. I. [PyElph - a software tool for gel images analysis and phylogenetics](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/1471-2105-13-9). BMC Bioinformatics 13, 9+ (2012).

You can download here
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyelph/